# No mount during boot; auto mount after boot

Tags: boot, mount, automount

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I have some mountable USB drives that cause the system to hang forever at boot time if it tries to mount them at that time, although the mounts work fine after the system is up and I'm logged in.

Here is a typical entry in `/etc/fstab` ...

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  /media/sdcard  ext4  defaults  0  0
```

I know that marking an entry in `/etc/fstab` with `noauto` will prevent the system from trying to mount it at boot time, since `noauto` causes the entry to be ignored when `mount -a` is run ... which occurs at boot time.

I have changed `defaults` to `defaults,noauto`, and now the boot runs normally.

However, then I can't run `mount -av` later to cause these devices to be mounted. If after boot, I remove `noauto` and then run `mount -av`, the devices then get properly mounted. The system hangs with these items only at boot time.

I would like to set up the system so that at boot time, those items are ignored, but that after boot, they can be mounted automatically ... for example, when I first log into my desktop session after boot.

I know I could write a script to grep through `/etc/fstab`, find these entries, and then cause each one of them to be manually mounted, and I could then cause that script to run at session startup time when I log in.

However, I'm wondering if there is some way to configure `/etc/fstab` so that those entries get ignored by `mount -a` **only** at boot time, and that they get mounted by `mount -a` once the system is up and I'm logged in.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try adding `nofail` to them as well.  `nofail` will bypass the mount if the device is not available.  Or maybe change `noauto` to `nofail`

Comment: Thank you. I had nofail, and it didn't change the behavior: the boot hung both with and without `nofail`.

Comment: If `noauto` is the only one that works, to mount you cannot use `mount -a` for it to work as `-a` means auto so they won't mount.  You would have to do `mount /media/sdcard` for the mount to work.  It will find that name and mount it.  Weird though that `nofail` doesn't work for you as it is only what I use for my drives that are USB in case they fail or are not plugged in at the time.

Comment: If you do try `nofail` again, do not add `noauto` to the line.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant option is `nobootwait`. Just in case someone (like me) is coming to this old thread.

Here you can find details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53456/what-is-the-difference-between-nobootwait-and-nofail-in-fstab